# Initializing arr_arr_integer

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

I'm working on the codesignal problem: Roads Building

I'm new to C, & struggling to intialize a arr_arr_integer.

I'm struggling to find examples in the same context & my intuition isn't upto scratch yet.

Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

============= Problem Description ====================================================

Given the existing roads and the number of cities in the kingdom, you should use the most modern technologies and find out which roads should be built again to connect each pair of cities. Since the crystal ball is quite old and meticulous, it will only transfer the information if it is sorted properly.

The roads to be built should be returned in an array sorted lexicographically,
with each road stored as [cityi, cityj], where cityi < cityj.

Example

For cities = 4 and roads = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0]],
the output should be
solution(cities, roads) = [[0, 3], [1, 3], [2, 3]].

==================================================================================

```
// Arrays are already defined with this interface:
// typedef struct arr_##name {
//   int size;
//   type *arr;
// } arr_##name;
//
// arr_##name alloc_arr_##name(int len) {
//   arr_##name a = {len, len > 0 ? malloc(sizeof(type) * len) : NULL};
//   return a;
// }
//
//

void minmax(int x, int y, int *min, int *max){
    if(x > y){
        *max = x;
        *min = y;
    }else{
        *max = y;
        *min = x;
    }
}
bool checkForward(arr_arr_integer roads, int i, int j, int k){
    if(roads.arr[k].arr[0] != i && roads.arr[k].arr[1] != j){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
bool checkBack(arr_arr_integer roads, int i, int j, int k){
    if(roads.arr[k].arr[1] != i && roads.arr[k].arr[0] != j){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
bool checkconnection(arr_arr_integer roads, int i, int j, int k){
    return (checkForward(roads, i, j, k) && checkBack(roads, i, j, k));
}

arr_arr_integer solution(int cities, arr_arr_integer roads) {
    // init res array
    arr_arr_integer resArrArr;
    resArrArr.size=0;
     resArrArr.arr = malloc(cities * cities * sizeof(arr_integer));  // 
    // loop through cities
    for(int i=0; i<cities; i++){
          // for each city, loop through all other cities of higher index
          for(int j =i; j<cities; j++){
              //loop through roads & check for edge from i <-> j
              for(int k =0; k < roads.size; k++){
                  // if no connection is present add to res array
                if(!checkconnection(roads, i, j, k)){
                    int min, max;
                    minmax(i, j, &min, &max);
                    arr_integer edge;
                    edge.size = 2;
                    edge.arr[0] = min;
                    edge.arr[1] = max;
                    resArrArr.arr[resArrArr.size] = edge;
                    resArrArr.size ++;
                }
              }
          }
        
    }
    return resArrArr;
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). What is the problem with the code you show? What is your question?

Comment: I cannot compile your code because it is incomplete. Please [edit] your question and show a [mre]. What exactly is your problem? If you get errors from the compiler, copy&paste the command(s) and the exact error message(s). Otherwise show the input you use, the actual output and the expected output.

Comment: To me your question is unclear. If you are asking "how to initialize a dynamic allocated array" the answer is "You can't"

Comment: My issue is 
a) I can't write a MRE without knowing how to construct the predefined arr_arr_integer type to pass into the solution function.
b) I am not getting any errors in my own editor due to b.

When using codesignal, the line of malloc is underlined, but It does not give any indication as to why. The definiton of arr_arr_integer is outlined in the comment at the top of the code block, I am struggling to understand how to construct it.

Comment: Your leading code comment appears to contain code extracted from one or more macro definitions.  I can probably guess the form of the original macro(s), more or less, but the code does not really make sense stand-alone.  And if you're supposed to use types such as those macros define, rather than bare arrays, then surely those macros, which you have not provided, are the key to doing so.

Comment: Furthermore, `arr_arr_integer` looks suspicious to me.  Are you sure it's not `arr_arr_int`?  If it's really \*integer, then there must also be a declaration somewhere of type `integer`, which you also have not disclosed.